# Eclipse project stop anywhere

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project which has Java server code opened in Eclipse.
I am not sure where it will be called by my client application.

I would like to stop anywhere control flows in my project.
How can I do that?

This question: [How to let the debugger stop anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797531/how-to-let-the-debugger-stop-anywhere) is slightly similar. However, the answer suggests reading about 'Symbolic Breakpoints' and I can't find any such thing for Eclipse.

Comment: Is it a web application ?

Comment: yes, it is a web app.

Comment: You know which request firing ?

Comment: Yes, but control doesn't go to where I was expecting in my project.

Comment: It should. Easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

This video explains how to set breakpoints in debug mode:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sKnGW1eXUM

Setting a breakpoint in the beginning of the code in the debug mode will let you step through the whole code and find a point where the Java Server code is being called.